# What are the correct arguments for ReadFile in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

So i'm trying to Read a file into a file buffer by using ReadFile, but every time it throws this exception

[image]

I don't understand why it has an access violation for writing, the file does exist, and I can see the file handle, buffer and file size in the Visual Studio autos watch

```
int main()
{
    LPCSTR Dll = "C:\\Test.dll";

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(Dll, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); // Open the DLL

    DWORD FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    PVOID FileBuffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Read the file
    ReadFile(hFile, FileBuffer, FileSize, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) says about the last two parameters:

> lpNumberOfBytesRead [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read when using a synchronous hFile parameter. ReadFile sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking. Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
>
> **This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.**

So you *should* call it with a pointer to a valid target to write to, instead of `NULL`:

```
DWORD outSize = 0;

ReadFile(hFile, FileBuffer, FileSize, &outSize, NULL);
```